# iPhone UDP listener

Tags: ios, objective-c, udp

I'm in need of some advice for how to accomplish something.

I'd like my iPhone app to listen for information from my server and then my server will send out data to all listening devices.

A few questions:

1. Will the iDevice need to "register" with the server with its IP? So, then on the server side, I store all listening device IPs in an array and fire out data to each.
2. Is there away for it to simply listen without the initial message?
3. Is UDP the way to go on this? Obviously I don't want a TCP stream because it's a constant connection. Uses too much data. My goal is use the least amount of data possible to receive a small timestamp from a server.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Elijah

Comment: I think Apple Push Notifications is the way to go.

Comment: But I don't want to send the user data, I need to send the app data. Can Apple Push Services do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use Apple Push Notifications, and you don't want to use long polling, I would look into something like [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

PHP has a very good implementation for it (I assume PHP is your server side language?) in [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

EDIT:

Just to elaborate a little, WebSockets will allow you to transmit from the server directly to the apps of every connected user at once, just like you are asking.

Comment: Awesome. I'll check it out. Yes, PHP is my server side language.

Comment: Cool. If that ends up looking correct, don't forget to accept my answer. :) Ratchet is super powerful, and easily integrates with frameworks like Symfony2.

Comment: Is this TCP though? I don't want a constant connection hogging up data.

Comment: It's TCP, yes, but there's no real reason to absolutely use UDP for this type of application. What you're describing as a "don't want" is HTTP which isn't the same thing as TCP.

Comment: Yeah it's a persistent connection. Will this hog up data? Or no more than UDP?

Comment: Oh, ok. Sweet. My main concern is data usage. The smaller the better.

Comment: No, it won't hog up a bunch of data. UDP is stateless while TCP is stateful, but that's more related to the networking layers of TCP than constant packets and keep-alive requests.

Comment: Excellent. I'll accept the answer in 3 minutes when it lets me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. :) I just had to research this topic at work, so I knew the answer right away.

Comment: I would use node.js as server side of choice here, since you want to use websockets and probably want to communicate to lot of devices at once, node is very good at that.

Comment: Just FYI, PHP using React/Ratchet is just as fast and just as good at this task. There's no real reason to rewrite your application in Node.js when PHP is just as good at this task.